# Limit posts from Instagram API on a Google Map based on radius in current window

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, instagram

So I have the code below which is the front end on a node.js app which pulls Instagram posts with a certain hashtag. Right now it posts all over the world. Is there a way to limit the radius on the posts and if possible, limit to the window that is currently visible to the user? I'm using the Instagram Real Time tag subscription.

```
function initialize() {

    var styles = [{
        "featureType": "landscape",
            "stylers": [{
            "color": "#808080"
        }, {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [{
            "weight": 0.1
        }, {
            "lightness": 100
        }, {
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {}];

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.71533, -117.15726),
        zoom: 4,
        scrollwheel: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        styles: styles
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);

    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('photo', function (data) {
        var icon = {
            url: data.img, // url
            size: new google.maps.Size(80, 80), // size
        };
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long),
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: icon,
            map: map,
            title: data.caption
        });
    });

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function () {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }

    var options = {
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
        content: content
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
    map.setCenter(options.position);
}

// Finally, call map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What is the issue here? The Maps API or the Instagram API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to combine endpoints, ie Geographies and Tags into one search. I would think you have 2 options and both will be fairly labour intensive on your end, depending on the popularity of the hashtag/s, and the radius of your geography. I'm interested to see more opinions on this.

## Option 1

- Keep your realtime Tag subscription
- Process the results manually to filter by the location information provided with each photo

Example from doc:

```
...
"location": {
    "latitude": 37.780885099999999,`
    "id": "514276",
    "longitude": -122.3948632,
    "name": "Instagram"
}
...
```

Pros:

- You've already got a tag subscription.
- You are not restricted to any radius

Cons:

- Figuring out what photos fall into your desired radius sounds pretty complicated.

## Option 2

- Create a realtime Geography subscription
- Process the results manually to filter by the tag information provided with each photo

Example from doc:

```
...
        "tags": ["expobar"],
...
```

Pros:

- Manually filtering by tag is likely going to be much easier

Cons:

- You're restricted to a max radius of 5000m in your geography subscription

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

I think you're confused between Locations and Geographies, what you describe in your last comment (thinking out loud) is *exactly* what I was trying to suggest in option 2. Locations are places where you can tag a photo when uploading, for instance 'Starbucks Downtown', and are not terribly useful IMO, whereas Geographies use latitude, longitude & a radius, and are perfect for what you want to achieve - finding and displaying photos taken in close proximity, no matter where the user is.

Check out the "Geography Subscriptions" section of http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/

Creating a Geography Subscription is very similar to a Tag subscription so it shouldn't take much to tinker with what you've already got. As you guessed, you will just need to use a javascript library to grab the users lat/longitude first

Comment: The unfortunate thing is they have a query limit, and I'd like to have a popular hashtag subscription but limit it's location. I can totally do this with one of your examples but it still queries Instagram. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's a popular hashtag, you'd want to go with option 2 above. Otherwise you're right, you'll end up getting hundreds (thousands?) of notifications, querying Instagram a lot (it's doesn't have to be 1-1 though, remember), and eventually filtering out a lot of the results because of their location. Not very efficient! If you get notifications based on location, you (probably) won't get nearly as many notifications. You'll still end up filtering out a lot of the results, based on hashtags, but at least option 2 will be more efficient.

Comment: The query limit (5000/hr) shouldn't be your problem, since if you are getting close to that, you should change your approach so that you only query Instagram for the new data every 5 or 10 notifications that you get

Comment: Right I totally understand, but I am pulling a real time location so option 1 is my only option. I am pulling #food, so I went over the limit right away! Haha.

Comment: Is it possible (thinking out loud here..) to maybe pull the user's location, then set the geo subscription with that? Then cancel the subscription when the page is closed? If so, some help in the right direction would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Instagram real-time API has a Geography Subscription as per [the documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) which allows you to specify a position and a radius.

*To create a subscription to a geography, specify a center latitude and longitude and a radius of the area you'd like to capture around that point (maximum radius is 5000 meters).*

We don't really know from your question where the issue is, so let's hope this helps.

Comment: As noted in my question, I'm using a Real Time "TAG" subscription which is instead of the Geography Subscription. I am wondering if there is a way to limit posts to a certain radius, WITH a TAG subscription. Thanks

Comment: Yes, then you will need to filter the results or switch to the geography subscription as explained in the later answer.