# Instagram API Real Time Updates for 2 object types

Tags: api, instagram

I need to be able to subscribe to Instagram for Real-Time updates using their API, but I'd like to subscribe to both geography and tags together (so that the callback only receives images with that tag and geographical location). Is this possible? Their docs just explain about subscribing to individual object types.

If it isn't possible (which is what I assume), if I subscribe to a geographical location which is fairly large (25mi), what's the feasibility of filtering out the images with a specific tag from all the images returned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instagram feed based on tag and geolocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068282/instagram-feed-based-on-tag-and-geolocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible directly through the API, and as you assumed will have to be done at your end. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068282/instagram-feed-based-on-tag-and-geolocation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870059/limit-posts-from-instagram-api-on-a-google-map-based-on-radius-in-current-window/21891047#21891047) for ideas on how to do it