# Search by location AND tags Instagram Api

Tags: php, api, tags, location, instagram

Is there any way I can get photos with a given tag AND location with instagram api? I'm using this call

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id
```

Yet I want to look for photos with that given tag in a given location but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram feed based on tag and geolocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068282/instagram-feed-based-on-tag-and-geolocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked and answered numerous times. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068282/instagram-feed-based-on-tag-and-geolocation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870059/limit-posts-from-instagram-api-on-a-google-map-based-on-radius-in-current-window) for some ideas. Short answer is to search by geolocation and then filter by tag or vice versa depending on what gets you best results